# Check given perforce label exists or not

Tags: perforce

I need to check whether a given label exists or not in a given server.

For example: label abc exists or not in a perforce server using `p4 labels` or `p4 describe` commands or any other relevant commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is `p4 labels -e abc`.  This will return the label if it exists, and nothing if it doesn't.